# Executing VBS via batch script in Jenkins

Tags: vbscript, jenkins, windows-server-2008

I have to execute the script on Window Server 2008. I use Jenkins for doing that. The batch code (MainCode.bat) is

```
cd "C:\temp"
cscript install.vbs
```

The install.vbs just installs the application in particular directory. The extract of the code is:

```
Set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
strCmd = "cmd /K C:\temp\InstallApp.exe -c -dir C:\ProductDir"
Wshshell.run (strCmd)
WScript.Sleep 2000
' choice of languages
WshShell.SendKeys "1"
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
    ...
```

To test this scripts I ran MainCode.bat on Window Server 2008 directly and **it worked** like a charm.
While running via Jenkins, the script doesn't execute. No error message and the installation is not done.

Via Jenkins the code to call MainCode.bat is

```
call "C:\temp\MainCode.bat".
```

Comment: What does the log for the Jenkins job say? Why do you conclude that the script doesn't execute? How do `MainCode.bat`, `install.vbs` and `InstallApp.exe` get copied into `C:\temp`? Can the commands for `InstallApp.exe` be improved so it doesn't need `SendKeys`? ("Real" installers can be used unattended, if not silently.)

Comment: @TomBlodget: Thank u for d Ques. I don't get a log for the Jenkins jobs rather I get console output which says 'C:\Temp>exit 0 
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: SUCCESS.' I conclude that the script doesn't execute by the fact that neither this dir C:\ProductDir is created, nor the installer is installed. I manually copy the MainCode.bat, install.vbs and InstallApp.exe to C:\Temp and then execute the ode through Jenkins. Though I have written the code for copying as well and it works.

Comment: So no problem with the copying. I think there is no other option rather than **Sendkeys** (though I have tried to make the code dynamic but its way to complicated so I am right now focusing on **Sendkeys** only). Hope I have answered your Q. :)

Comment: I think that SendKeys might not work if you are running Jenkins as a Windows service under a system account. You can try it as a Windows service under a user account, as well as running it directly with `java.exe`. You can trace what processes are created using Sysinternal's Process Monitor.

Comment: @Kriti  how was your jenkins setup ? As a service or a war file run ? Is it a slave machine and the user has elevated permissions ?

Comment: Try allowing the service to interact with the desktop. Run "Services", right-click on the Jenkins service and select Properties. On the Log On tab, turn on "Allow service to interact with desktop."

Answer (score 4):

As you are using SendKeys I assume the process you run is GUI application. You are probably running Jenkins slave under headless mode as windows service, in this case GUI application will have problems. You should run Jenkins slave agent as jnlp.